# JS / TS determine if a JSON object implements a class or interface

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON object parsed from a string.
Let's say this object has a property called "Name" the value of it can be a simple string or an array of strings or even an object that store some information about it.

In runtime I want to be able to find the value type (string/array/object)  and if it is an object cast it into the correct class and run a method based on that.

I have the idea on how I am going to go about this but the only problem is that I am not sure how to convert the object to the correct type.

For example, I have a class which accepts two strings and another class that accepts a string and a number. I want the program to see which one it matches and then cast it to the correct class.

Hope I was clear enough if more information is needed please let me know.

EDIT:

Here is the solution I used to make this work (at least for me, it may not be the best solution in every case).

I have an abstract class called Parser

```
    export abstract class Parser {
    abstract parse(): string;

    clone(dataObject: object): Parser {
        if (this.validateData(dataObject) == false) return null;
        return this.cloneObject(dataObject);
    }
    protected abstract cloneObject(dataObject: object): Parser;

    protected validateData(data: object): boolean {
        const parserKeys = Object.keys(this);
        const dataKeys = Object.keys(data);

        for (let i = 0; i < parserKeys.length; i++) {
            const parserKeyName = parserKeys[i];

            if (typeof this[parserKeyName] === "function") continue;
            const index = dataKeys.indexOf(parserKeyName);
            if (
                index == -1 ||
                typeof data[dataKeys[i]] !== typeof this[parserKeyName]
            )
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

It has the method validateData which takes an object (the JSON Object usually) and validate that it has all the variables the Parser has.
If the data is valid it will call a protected abstract method called cloneObject.

Here is a simple class called MinMaxParrser that extends Parser

```
import { Parser } from "./Parser";
import { randomNumber } from "./utils";

export class MinMaxParser extends Parser {
        min: 0;
        max: 1;
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.min = 0;
            this.max = 1;
        }
        parse(): string {
            return randomNumber(this.min, this.max).toString();
        }

        cloneObject(dataObject: object): MinMaxParser {
            let newParser = new MinMaxParser();
            newParser.min = dataObject["min"];
            newParser.max = dataObject["max"];

            return newParser;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it has the cloneObject method which basically returns an instance of a new MinMaxParser

And finally, in the main program, I have a const array of all the available parsers by declaring a "sample" object

```
const availableParsers: Parser[] = [new MinMaxParser()];
```

When I want to find a valid parser I use this method

```
private findValidParser(data: Object): Parser {
    let found = null;
    availableParsers.forEach(parser => {
        let clone = parser.clone(data);
        if (clone !== null) {
            found = clone;
        }
    });

    return found;
}
```

The findValidParser returns me a parser or null, I check for null and if it is not null i can safely call the parse() method i created.

Comment: Would you add some samples instead of describing them so heavily on words, please?

Comment: Before continuing, please read about [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: Have you tried using typeof, maybe with switch/case?

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(what_ever_object)` returns a "class" of an object.

Comment: It may just be loose usage of terms but you cannot cast a JSON literal (which is what you get when parse a string) to a class.  You can cast it to an interface though.

Comment: I've used [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) for runtime JSON checking in past projects. There's a bit of a learning curve but it definitely gets the job done.

Comment: @vahdet Sorry, I am on mobile, therefore, I cannot provide an accurate coding example but I am going to have an interface that is called parser with a method called parse. Now I will have a couple of classes that implement this interface each accepting different values. I kinda want to have something that will take a look at these classes and the JSON object and then create a new instance of the correct class by passing the data from the JSON object to the constructor of that class and finally it will call the parse method. This may sound a bit complicated though. I'll give a code example soon

Comment: I don't want to use switch statements yet. It is probably the easiest solution but I don't want the code to be flooded with switch statement. I'd use them as last resort if I cannot find the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `typeof` and function overloads to get better type hints:

```
// narrow down types to get better typings
function parse(a: string, b: {}, c: string): Parser1;
//...

// implement generically
function parse(a: any, b: any, c: any): Parser {
 if(typeof a === "string" && typeof b === "object" && typeof c === "string") {
   return Parser1.parse(a, b, c);
 } /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks that kinda what I was looking for. But instead of making a lot of if statements I will probably make a function that will look at the class and compare it for me and then create an instance based on that (it will probably be a bit hacky though). I will post full code solution later today when I get home and coded it. And if I encounter another problem I will post here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to check each

```js
let obj = {};
let str = '';
let num = 0;
let array = [];

console.log(Array.isArray(array))
console.log(typeof obj === 'object')
console.log(typeof str === 'string')
console.log(!isNaN(num))
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I am really struggling with is if the type is an object I want to make it an instance of a class based on the data of the object.

Comment: make it an instance of the class? you want to convert the object into an instance of class? it must be already an instance else you cant.